# Camunda printing on console through inline script

Tags: groovy, camunda, camunda-modeler

I installed camunda bpm engine and I am trying to make a simple test to understand how inline scripts work. I have the following process

[my simple process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d10li.png)

However, the console from which I am running the camunda bpm platform shows nothing. Does anyone know how to make this work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `scriptFormat="groovy"` to let camunda know how to handle the script. You can do this by typing `groovy` in the modeler form field.

See [script task documentation](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.14/reference/bpmn20/tasks/script-task/).